# Tesseract tessdata folder not found when put in assets folder

Tags: android, tesseract

I read everywhere that tessdata should be on external storage and there should be `eng.traineddata` for `eng` language. But how to package application to device so it will be there ? I don't know about this is possible so I copied `tessdata` to `assets` folder. I can access it by `context().getAssets().openFd().open("tessdata/eng.traineddata")` but when I when I try !`new File("file:///android_asset/tessdata/").exists()` it is not found and I get exception from tesseract library when initialising , that it is not found. I am using Genymotion as emulator and somehow that direct path is not correct. So I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have seen another example on github an he is copying traineddata from assets to sdcard if data there do not exist. So this is the only way probably.

```
 private void initializeTessApi() {
    _tessApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    File data = new File(application().dataDir(), TESSDATA);
    File traineddataFile = new File(data, LANG + ".traineddata");
    if (!traineddataFile.exists()) {
        try {
            data.mkdirs();
            copyAndClose(context().getAssets().open(TESSDATA + "/" + LANG + ".traineddata"), new FileOutputStream(traineddataFile));
            info("Copied", LANG, "traineddata");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error(e, "Was unable to copy", LANG, "traineddata ");
        }
    }
    _tessApi.init(application().dataDir().getAbsolutePath(), LANG);
}
```